# npm run build is throwing errors in my vue cli project but npm run dev works fine

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

When I run npm run build I get a bunch of errors, but when I run npm run dev, it works fine without errors.

I tried changing webpack.config.js public path to ./dist but that didn't fix it. I also tried installing uglifyjs but it didn't help either. I don't know what else to try.

Here is my webpack.config.js file

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: './dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{

  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.6",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

When I run npm run build, it should create a dist folder including all necessary files to run in production mode. Instead I am getting these errors

```
/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:74
                                throw err;
                                ^

Error: webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead.
    at Object.get [as UglifyJsPlugin] (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:185:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/webpack.config.js:75:26)
    at Module._compile (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:663:17)
    at require (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:115:13)
    at requireConfig (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:117:6)
    at /Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:124:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:122:15)
    at yargs.parse (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45)
    at Object.parse (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:567:18)
    at /Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:375:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:663:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:156:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:526:15)
    at startMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:439:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! iread@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the iread@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pat/.npm/_logs/2019-05-23T17_34_37_411Z-debug.log
Patricks-MacBook-Pro:iread pat$ npm run build

> iread@1.0.0 build /Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules

/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:74
                                throw err;
                                ^

Error: webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead.
    at Object.get [as UglifyJsPlugin] (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:185:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/webpack.config.js:75:26)
    at Module._compile (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:663:17)
    at require (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:115:13)
    at requireConfig (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:117:6)
    at /Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:124:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:122:15)
    at yargs.parse (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45)
    at Object.parse (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:567:18)
    at /Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:375:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:663:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pat/Desktop/side/iread/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:156:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:526:15)
    at startMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:439:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! iread@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the iread@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pat/.npm/_logs/2019-05-23T17_34_58_975Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Looks like you're modifying the webpack config file which you typically don't do directly with Vue CLI 3. If you're using an older version of Vue CLI, I recommend using 3 instead. It's a lot nicer and cleaner, trust me. Even has typescript and scss that you can apply to components right off of install. Even setting up the proxy for the frontend and backend server is super easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I finally figure it out. In my webpack.config.js I changed

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
```

to this

```
optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
  },
```

The problem was that I was adding the minimizer without removing the old new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin. 
I found the answer from their [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it because you don't use the uglifyJS dependency in Dev build, try to run an npm install and then try build again

Edit: check this  out 
https://github.com/wuweijia/wuweijia.github.io/issues/46

Answer (score 0):

try to run the following command

*npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save*

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can exclude files from the build.
In your tsconfig.json file,
change the include

```
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
```

to exclude

```
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
```

Please make sure you don't have any errors in dev mode.